# How long ago was the last known location recorded?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, gps

I am getting my last known location but not how long it has been since my location was last updated. How can I find out how long it has been since the location was last updated?

```
LocationManager locationManager 
                        = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria c = new Criteria();
    c.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    c.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
    c.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    c.setBearingRequired(false);
    c.setCostAllowed(true);
    c.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(c, true);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

Comment: How about subscribing to location updates and measuring the time difference between the received updates? When you get a location update, the Location instance let's you retrieve the time of the update via getTime() (beware though, it's in UTC).

Comment: [`location.getTime();`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getTime%28%29) talks about [`getElapsedRealtimeNanos()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getElapsedRealtimeNanos%28%29) to calculate the age of a fix and to compare Location fixes. The [example](https://code.google.com/p/android-protips-location/source/browse/trunk/src/com/radioactiveyak/location_best_practices/utils/GingerbreadLastLocationFinder.java) at [the blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html) uses `getTime()`.

Comment: getElapsedRealtimeNanos() is the recommended approach going forward, but is only available in API 17 (4.2) and above, so getTime is really the only thing to use as of time of writing...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Best option for both pre and post API 17:

```
public int age_minutes(Location last) {
    return age_ms(last) / (60*1000);
}

public long age_ms(Location last) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        return age_ms_api_17(last);
    return age_ms_api_pre_17(last);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
private long age_ms_api_17(Location last) {
    return (SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() - last
            .getElapsedRealtimeNanos()) / 1000000;
}

private long age_ms_api_pre_17(Location last) {
    return System.currentTimeMillis() - last.getTime();
}
```

The pre 17 is not very accurate, but should be sufficient to test if a location is very old.

This, I should think, would be OK:

```
if (age_minutes(lastLoc) < 5) {
   // fix is under 5 mins old, we'll use it

} else {
   // older than 5 mins, we'll ignore it and wait for new one

}
```

The usual use case for this logic is when the app has just started and we need to know whether we **must** wait for a new location or can use the latest for now while we wait for a new location.

Comment: I believe this solution has one flaw - imagine if I had lastLocation stored in some persistence storage. Let's say I got last location update 3 hours since the last phone reboot. This location update is stored in a storage. Then I reboot my phone again and call "age_minutes(last)". I would get SystemClock = ~1min and lastLocation=3hours. "age_minutes" would return true which is not correct.

Comment: @Michal The flaw is thinking you store the last location yourself. Always ask the `locationManager` & `provider` as per the line in the question: `Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);`

Comment: @Michal if you don't do that and store the last location yourself, then in addition to causing the bug you talk about, you won't benefit from other apps requesting a location.

Comment: You are right, we should always be using the last location from provider Android gives so it does work well for the question asked here. I was looking at it as a testable code snippet.

Comment: Although, u shouldn't be storing the last location urself, but if u really want to, u can add a check something like `age_minutes(lastLoc) > 0` which will solve the case that @Michal mentioned in the first comment. No?

Comment: If you go against my advice and persist a `Location`, then post API 17 `age_minutes` will always be `> 0`. You should not try to solve problems you do not have, just ask the location manager.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry to reopen this, but I think weston's answer is incorrect,
and the Android documentation is at least misleading.

The time base for getTime() is UTC as determined from the
NMEA sentence received from the GPS module, *not* System.currentTimeMillis().  GPS
time is precise to the nanoseconds (it has to be since electromagnetic waves travel 30cm in 1ns).  The
only complication here is that it may be off by 1s due
to a GPS leap second (see [1]; this can happen
during a few minutes every few years, assuming that the GPS is intelligent enough to remember the UTC offset across power cycles)

On the other hand, System.currentTimeMillis() can be off by several
seconds/minutes due to drift or even more if the user sets time/date incorrectly.

So the only real solution pre-API 17 is 
to receive location updates regularly and each time record
your own timestamp based on SystemClock.elapsedRealtime().

I just tried this on a Samsung S4, please correct me if other phones
give different results.  I doubt it, though.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#Leap_seconds

Comment: I think you're correct. Only just seen this by chance. You should post critiques as a comment on my answer or else I won't see it.

Comment: If I get another upvote, I'll have enough reputation to post comments :)   (this one seems to be an exception since I'm replying to my own post)

Comment: What is your method for getting elapsed times between reboots using SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()?

Comment: Can someone comment on what the maximum error is in Location.getTime()?

Answer (score 5):

Location.getTime() is actually not the best way to find the age of the last known location.

From the JavaDoc:

> Return the UTC time of this fix, in milliseconds since January 1, 1970.
>
> Note that the UTC time on a device is not monotonic: it can jump forwards or backwards unpredictably. So always use getElapsedRealtimeNanos when calculating time deltas.

The two methods to use are:

```
SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();
Location.getElapsedRealtimeNanos();
```

Note also that LocationManager.lastKnownLocation() may return null.

Answer (score 1):

Each location has an attribute time. Get it with `getTime().` Compare it with current time. (Calculate the difference). This gives you the "age".